# .htaccess rewrite rule for subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I would like to write a rule in my .htaccess to rewrite the url to enable my subdomain to show the content of a page from my site.

For example, I would like `http://subdomain.example.org/page` to show the content of the page `http://example.org/subdomain/page`.

I tried to write some rules as follow but it did not work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!subdomain).*)$ example.org/subdomain/$1 [NC,L]
```

Those rules end up raising an Internal Server Error

I also tried the last rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.example.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/subdomain$1 [L]
```

But this rule end up redirecting to `http://example.org/subdomain` and not just showing the content of the page while keeping the url.

What should be the right way to write the rule ?

Comment: Without using the rules , what folder does your subdomain point to?

Comment: Currently my subdomain is empty

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/$1 [L]` looks like it should work then. Can you please check your error log there will be more information about the 500 internal server error.

Comment: The error is : "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error". But I don't understand why I get an infinite loop.

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: I tried removing them all but nothing changed

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: I do not understand that second rule you use. 1. `example.org/subdomain/$1` is _not_ a URL, so it tries to map requests to a _folder_ `example.org`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: For sure you will end up _redirecting_ to the `example.org` host using the last rule modified to rewrite to a URL instead of a folder... This also is not what you want, if I understand your question right... So why that second rule at all? What is it meant to do?

Comment: All rules have the same purpose, I just tried several ways since none of them worked